# Parsing Google News RSS with PHP

Tags: php, rss

I want to parse Google News rss with PHP. I managed to run this code:

```
<?
$news = simplexml_load_file('http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss');

foreach($news->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<strong>" . $item->title . "</strong><br />";
    echo strip_tags($item->description) ."<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

However, I'm unable to solve following problems. For example:

1. How can i get the hyperlink of the news title?
2. As each of the Google news has many related news links in footer, (and my code above includes them also). How can I remove those from the description?
3. How can i get the image of each news also? (Google displays a thumbnail image of each news)

Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

There we go, just what you need for your particular situation:

```
<?php
$news = simplexml_load_file('http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss');

$feeds = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($news->channel->item as $item) 
{
    preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@', $item->description, $match);
    $parts = explode('<font size="-1">', $item->description);

    $feeds[$i]['title'] = (string) $item->title;
    $feeds[$i]['link'] = (string) $item->link;
    $feeds[$i]['image'] = $match[1];
    $feeds[$i]['site_title'] = strip_tags($parts[1]);
    $feeds[$i]['story'] = strip_tags($parts[2]);

    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($feeds);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And the output should look like this:

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Los Alamos Nuclear Lab Under Siege From Wildfire - ABC News
            [link] => http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGxBe4YsZArH0kSwEjq_zDm_h-N4A&url=http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/wireStory?id%3D13951623
            [image] => http://nt2.ggpht.com/news/tbn/OhH43xORRwiW1M/6.jpg
            [site_title] => ABC News
            [story] => A wildfire burning near the desert birthplace of the atomic bomb advanced on the Los Alamos laboratory and thousands of outdoor drums of plutonium-contaminated waste Tuesday as authorities stepped up ...
        )
```

Comment: @IvanCachicatari You say it works like a charm, did you manage to get image data from the RSS? I can't seem to be able to, it would appear google news RSS (at least for me) has no image section, an 80x80 image can be found under a "gstatic" URL, not the "ggpht" url seen in the answer above. Any suggestions? Cheers.

Comment: @Aphire one option is go to URL and get the main image from HTML on site, the gstatic is only a thumbnail

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend checking out [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/). I've used it for several different projects and it works great (and abstracts away all of the headache you're currently dealing with).

Now, if you're writing this code simply because you want to learn how to do it, you should probably ignore this answer. :)

Comment: Not worth posting as a new answer, but Magpie http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/ is another possible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the URL for a news item, use $item->link.
2. If there's a common delimiter for the related news links, you could use regex to cut off everything after it.
3. Google puts the thumbnail image HTML code inside the description field of the feed.  You could regex out everything between the open and close brackets for the image declaration to get the HTML for it.