# Parsing Google News RSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

Want to parse Google News rss with Javascript. I managed to run this code in PHP code form [How Parse Google News in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512318/parsing-google-news-rss-with-php):

My question is how can i do the same thing in Javascript code
for example parse: http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&output=rss&cf=all&topic=topics&q=obama&hl=en&num=10 and get data about different news there

Thanks.

Comment: That's great. What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. As it currently stands it is unclear what you are asking. Please take the [tour] on how to ask your question.

Comment: My question is how can i do the same thing in Javascript code

Answer (score 1):

The data you obtained are in XML format.

You can access all the items using a `DOMParser`. See: [XML Parser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

**Example**

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
console.log(items);
```

**Working Example**

```
// [1] Parse the xml feed into an array of JS objects
function parseData(data) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");

  // Convert collection to array
  // getElementsByTagName returns a collection/NodeList instead of an array.
  // It will be more convenient if we could use it like an array.
  var items = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('item'));

  var feeds = [];
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    feeds.push({
      title: getNode(item, 'title'),
      link: getNode(item, 'link'),
      pubDate: getNode(item, 'pubDate'),
      description: getNode(item, 'description'),
    });
  });
  return feeds;
}

// Retrieve the data of a specific tag
function getNode(node, tagToRetrieve) {
  var htmlData = node.getElementsByTagName(tagToRetrieve)[0].innerHTML;
  return _.unescape(htmlData); // decode HTML entities, see lodash/underscore
}
```

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/amoshydra/ao0tacs6/

Comment: Thanks but is possible to write an example for Google news rss code its very difficult for me create something that work with for example http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&output=rss&cf=all&topic=topics&q=obama&hl=en&num=10

Comment: Amos Wong i have tried your solution with jsfiddle but there are no result